# weird word considers two pages in a row as odd and mis counting

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

After the page 13 in my document, words tells me that I am in page 15

I'm not talking about page numbering, but about the total page number that appears at the button, i mean this one:

[image]

It's really weird that after page 13, there is page 15, knowing that there is a section break at the end of page 13

If you don't believe me, look at this header and footer, it's the footer of the page 13, followed by the header of the page 15 (which should be page 14 )

[image]

both are odd, though one should be 13, yes odd, but the other should have been 14 (even), but word for someway eats the page 14 and put 15
I'm using word 2011 on macbook pro

Comment: Have you tried saving the document, closing Word, and reloading the doc? If that does not help, look for hidden characters, e.g.page break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of section break is at the end of page 13?  If it is a Section Break (Odd Page) that will force the next page to be the next odd number in the sequence, in this case 15.

It should be Section Break (Next Page) if you want the page numbering to continue on in sequence.